# Reload target platform in eclipse dynamically from plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin to eclipse, in which I need to reload active target platform, at a given time. - just as the Preferences -> Plug-In Development -> Target Platform -> Reload.button, but of course dynamically from my plugin.

I would imagine something like this would be the way, but i can't find the entrance/MagicProvider:

```
MagicProvider.getTargetPlatforms().getActive().reload();
```

Hope some of you know the trick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried Max's approach, but it didn't seem to work. After searching the eclipse source I found out, that the ITargetDefinition is just a working copy, and must be saved. So the code will be:

```
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetPlatformService service = org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDECore.getDefault().acquireService(ITargetPlatformService.class.getName());
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetDefinition target = service.getWorkspaceTargetHandle().getTargetDefinition();
target.resolve(IProgressMonitor);
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.LoadTargetDefinitionJob.load(target);
```

But credits to Max for the guideline. :)

If anyone else needs some info, I recommend taking a look at

`org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.preferences.TargetPlatformPreferencePage` near line 771 - 812 and method handleReload()
and `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.targetdefinition.TargetEditor` near line line 231

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetPlatformService service = org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDECore.getDefault().acquireService(ITargetPlatformService.class.getName());
org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.provisional.ITargetDefinition target = service.getWorkspaceTargetHandle().getTargetDefinition();
target.resolve(IProgressMonitor);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOSX + eclipse Juno:
I get an exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/pde/internal/core/target/provisional/ITargetPlatformService
works on Linux and Win32.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 2020-09 it works for me as...

```
import org.eclipse.pde.core.target.ITargetDefinition;
import org.eclipse.pde.core.target.ITargetPlatformService;
import org.eclipse.pde.core.target.LoadTargetDefinitionJob;
...
    BundleContext context = ... from Activator.start() method
    ServiceReference<ITargetPlatformService> ref = context.getServiceReference(ITargetPlatformService.class);
    ITargetPlatformService service = context.getService(ref);
    ITargetDefinition def = service.getWorkspaceTargetDefinition();
    def.resolve(new NullProgressMonitor());
    LoadTargetDefinitionJob.load(def);
```

Add dependency org.eclipse.pde.core in your plugin.xml